# Same smart contract file , different sizes?

Tags: ethereum, filesize, smartcontracts

I am performing a stress test using Ethereum Ropsten test net, using the examples from [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/solidity-by-example.html) , have deployed several contracts in loop, but found that it is showing two file sizes, however I believe file size should be same as am deploying the same contract, with same arguments again and again. Please help me understand this.

Comment: What do you mean by file size? And what is the 'it' which is showing you this 'file size'?

Comment: I am calculating file size in python code before deploying contract to Ropsten Test Net.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the problem was the size of arguments were different.